# django use column value for filtering

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have a table of points with location data as stored in the following columns:

```
coordinates: the geolocation data in longitude and latitude
radius:      the distance from coordinate that it is visible
```

Now I take a random point and want to find the points that are visible to the random point using django geolocation such as:

```
LocationInfo.objects.filter(coordinates__distance_lt=(random_point, D(km=1))
```

Currently I am retrieving the points within 1 km radius but I want to use the radius from the table. How can I use the radius from the table?

Comment: replace `km=1` with `km=theVariableYouWant`

Comment: I want to use the value stored in the radius column of the database

Comment: well provide me with the model code for it, so I can show you the code. You simply have to fetch it `modelName.objects.get(id=yourDesiredId)` or instead of ID whatever else you need to fetch it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

```
from django.db.models import F

LocationInfo.objects.filter(
    coordinates__distance_lt=(random_point, D(km=F('FIELD_NAME'))
)
#                                               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i get the error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number when i try D(km=F('radius')) while radius is a floatfield

Comment: D is imported from django.contrib.gis.measure import D